# Having constant vertical spacing to space exactly halfway down the page

Tags: spacing, pdftex, miktex

I am writing a test in LaTeX and there needs to be the same question on the page twice, a second time halfway down the page. What I have been doing is simply adding a `\vspace` (or `\vspace{\stretch{1}}`)and manually spacing the question halfway down based on how many lines it is originally. How can I space it regardless of how long a question is (provided that it is less than half the page) so that the duplicate of the question appears halfway down the page? Thank you in advance.

Comment: place the text in a minipage and use the optional argument to specify the height of the minipage is .5\textheight (or a bit less) then just stack the two boxes

Comment: You could also typeset the document for paper of half the size (e.g. see the `geometry` package to set dimensions), then double it later (either in TeX or as late as when sending to the printer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\vspace*{\fill}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}

\newcommand{\doublequestion}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  #1\par
  \vspace*{\fill}
  #1\par
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \clearpage
}
\flushbottom

\begin{document}

\doublequestion{This question is very short, isn't it?}

\doublequestion{\lipsum[1-2]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this will help me a lot, I just have a question. What does the `\doublequestion{\lipsum[1-2]}` do?

Comment: @TehRod `\lipsum[1-2]` prints two paragraphs of nonsense pseudo-Latin text (you see it on page 2). Just a way to print a long “question” without thinking to some witty text.